# How to add f1, f2 and f3 (three outputs of tree void functions) in the main function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>



using namespace std;

    class solution
    {
    float x;

    public:
        void quad_f();
        void cube_f();
        void bi_quad_f();

    };

    void solution::quad_f()
    {
                float f1;
                cout << "Enter the value of x:" << endl;
                cin >> x;
                f1 = 4*pow(x,2) + 3*x + 1;
                cout << f1 << endl;

    }

    void solution::cube_f()

    {
                cout << "Enter the value of x:" << endl;
                cin >> x;
                float f2 = pow(x,3) + 1;
                cout << f2 << endl;

    }

    void solution::bi_quad_f()

    {
                cout << "Enter the value of x:" << endl;
                cin >> x;
                float f3 = pow(x,4);
                cout << f3 << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
       solution collector;

       collector.quad_f();
       collector.cube_f();
       collector.bi_quad_f();



        return 0;
    }
```

I have declared three functions in a class and defined them one-by-one
to get final output. now i am able to get each out put separately.
But, i want to add f1, f2 and f3 from above three functions in below
main functions to get a single output.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to return `f1, f2 and f3` from your member functions. Then you can add them together and print them in `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

class solution
{
    float x;

public:
    float quad_f();
    float cube_f();
    float bi_quad_f();
};

float solution::quad_f()
{
    float f1;
    cout << "Enter the value of x:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    f1 = 4*pow(x,2) + 3*x + 1;
    cout << f1 << endl;
    return f1;
}

float solution::cube_f()
{
    cout << "Enter the value of x:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    float f2 = pow(x,3) + 1;
    cout << f2 << endl;
    return f2;
}

float solution::bi_quad_f()
{
    cout << "Enter the value of x:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    float f3 = pow(x,4);
    cout << f3 << endl;
    return f3;
}

int main()
{
   solution collector;

   float result = collector.quad_f();
   result += collector.cube_f();
   result += collector.bi_quad_f();

   cout << "Totalt result is: " << result << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Note that now `x` is not really being used in any meaningful way. You could input directly to `f1, f2 and f3` and get the same results.

There are of course other ways to approach this. You could add the result of the functions to `x` and have a separate member function that will print the current value of `x`. It's not really clear exactly what you are looking for though.

Comment: You should change the return type of all these functions to `float` in function definition.

Comment: Indeed, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: great help indeed!